# How to get OBJECT value from Map of Maps

Tags: apex

I am trying to pull the object values out of a map of maps and just cant figure out how to do so. Is what I am trying to achieve even possible?

Here is my code that I am working with. The line I am struggling to figure out is:

```
ass.Assignee_First_Name__c = assetMap.get(string)csvValues.get('first name');
```

```
global class assetUpdater implements Messaging.InboundEmailHandler {
    global Messaging.InboundEmailResult handleInboundEmail(Messaging.InboundEmail email, Messaging.InboundEnvelope envelope) {
        Messaging.InboundEmailResult result = new Messaging.InboundEmailresult();

        for (Messaging.InboundEmail.BinaryAttachment att : email.binaryAttachments) {

            if (att.fileName == 'Asset Master.csv') {
                string nameFile = att.body.toString();
                system.debug('nameFile ' + nameFile);
                system.debug(att.body.toString());
                String[] filelines = new String[] {};
                filelines = nameFile.split('\n');

                Map<String, map<String, Object>> assetMap  = new Map<String, map<String, Object>>();
                Map<string, object> assetValues = new Map<String, object>();
                List<Asset__c> assetList = new List<Asset__c>();

                for (Integer i = 1; i < filelines.size(); i++) {
                    String[] inputValues = new String[] {};
                    inputValues = filelines[i].split(',');

                    Map<String, Object> csvValues = new Map<String, Object>();

                    //Map all the CSV Values to the csvValuesMAP
                    csvValues.put('serial number', inputValues[0]);
                    csvValues.put('name', inputvalues[1]);
                    csvValues.put('Lease End Date', inputvalues[2]);
                    csvValues.put('Monthly Cost', inputvalues[3]);
                    csvValues.put('In Both List', inputvalues[4]);
                    csvValues.put('first name', inputvalues[5]);
                    csvValues.put('last name', inputvalues[6]);
                    csvValues.put('verified', inputvalues[7]);
                    csvValues.put('city', inputvalues[8]);

                    assetMap.put(inputValues[0], csvValues);
                    system.debug('TEST ' + assetMap);
                    system.debug('numberserial ' + assetMap.keyset());
                    system.debug('csvValues ' + csvValues.get('serial number'));
                }

                List<asset__c> asset = [SELECT id, serial_number__c, Assignee_First_Name__c, Assignee_Last_Name__c FROM asset__c WHERE serial_number__c IN : assetMap.keySet()];
                system.debug('assetTEST ' + asset);
                for (asset__c ass : asset) {
                    ass.Assignee_First_Name__c = assetMap.get(string)csvValues.get('first name');
                }
                update (assetList);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

As you can see I am parsing the values of a CSV and attempting to update Asset records if the CSV values do not match the values of the Assets in our Salesforce Database. I am simply starting out by trying to update the name of who owns the asset..

Comment: Please do not use the `[community]` tag unless you are asking a question about the `Salesforce Communities` feature.

Comment: Whoops my bad ! @AdrianLarson

Comment: Side note: Avoid variable names that many be construed as a rude/explicit word. Hint: avoiding three- and four-letter words will help avoid "bad" words if you're not terribly familiar with English curse words.

Answer (score 2):

If I got you data model right than you need something like that

```
ass.Assignee_First_Name__c = assetMap.get(asset.serial_number__c).get('first name'));
```

anyway when you work with map of maps you have to extract map by a key and them extract value out of the second map again

```
Map<String, Map<String, Object>> m1 = new Map<String, Map<String, Object>> ();
Map<String, Object> m2 = m1.get(key1);
Object result = m2.get(key2);

// or 

m1.get(key1).get(key2);
```